# Are there any good alternatives to the Compass sprite generator? (Rails sprite generators)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css-sprites, compass

I was wondering if there are any libraries out there that do what the Compass sprite generator does? I absolutely love that feature of Compass, but I don't want the rest of the framework. I just want something that creates a sprite with a folder full of PNGs and maybe creates some CSS classes I can use to display the graphics in the sprite. I've done a little poking around, and I see a lot of sprite generators as web apps. Do people use these for high-traffic sites? Or do people generally maintain their own sprites using Photoshop or some better tool? Any info is most appreciated!

Comment: I must have this tagged or described poorly, because I can't believe there isn't more input for a question like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer myself, yes, there are a few options:

https://github.com/jakesgordon/sprite-factory

https://github.com/aslansky/css-sprite

https://github.com/wellington/wellington